# Imgur upload api error always returning 400 with multer and form-data nodejs

Tags: node.js, multer, form-data, imgur

I'm using react antd to upload pictures. Here's my express handling the upload request:

```
router.post('/upload-image', upload.any(), async function(req, res, next) {
    const file = req.files[0];
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('image', file.buffer);
    form.append('type', 'file');

    const imgurInstance = new imgur({
        refreshToken: user.imgurRefreshToken,
        clientId: IMGUR_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: IMGUR_CLIENT_SECRET
    });

    await imgurInstance.getAccessToken();
    const response = await imgurInstance.uploadImage(form);
    const data = await response.json();
});
```

Here's the req.files[0] console logged:

```
{
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'headscratch.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00 42 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 01 87 69 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 ... 13803 more bytes>,
  size: 13853
}
```

And here's my uploadImage function using node-fetch

```
uploadImage (form){
    const path = `/3/upload`;
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
        ...form.getHeaders()
    };
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: form,
        headers
    };

    return fetch(`${this.BASE_API_URL}${path}`, options);
}
```

I always get a 400 from imgur and they don't provide any details why.

```
{
  status: 400,
  success: false,
  data: { error: 'Bad Request', request: '/3/upload', method: 'POST' }
}
```

I have tried using base64, just uploading a url using form-data and I still get a 400 error. Does anybody have any guidance on how to successfully make this call work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I needed to understand what form-data is actually doing. Apparently form-data won't send as a file unless you include the filename with {filename: ''} as an option

```
form.append('image', file.buffer, {filename: file.originalname});
```

imgur finally accepted my request and voila.